# AWS VPC lattice always return 503

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am trying to play with AWS VPC Lattice. I have created a very simple configuration

1. basic VPC
2. service netwrok with security group
3. target group to instance
4. target group to ip
5. service that when there is a call over https - route to the ip target and when there is a call to http route to the instance

I am doing a basic curl call to the service dns, and matter if i call using http or https
I am always getting 503.

all the calls are made from EC2, when I call directly the IP or the instance IP - all is fine.

I have enabled health on the targets and I am getting errors - but they are healthy

does anyone had same behavior?